# Error when importing data from CSV ,"Specific argument was out of the range of valid values"

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I've been getting an error when trying to import a csv file as a data source using "from text". I do this all the time but I get this specific error with a specific very large csv file. Obviously, I think the problem is with the csv file but I'm not sure what to check. I've also tried changing the file origin setting on import too with no luck.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

[Specific argument was out of the range of valid values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3PXd.png)

Comment: How many rows in the csv?

Comment: @ScottCraner around 4000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think the problem is with the csv file

That's true.

> I'm not sure what to check

Firstly - alter datatype for one column with non-TEXT type to text in "master of import" settings, and import. If fail - alter another additionally. You'll find the column with problematic value (if there is more than one such column you'll find the last of them). After a problematic column found fix its datatype as text, and use correct datatype for all another columns - if fail search for another problematic column. Find all problematic columns.

After successful import investigate the problematic column values (use pivot or look at values list in autofilter, for example) - if it cannot be found "by eye" then you may try to convert this column value into the correct datatype in additional column using according worksheet formula and check for error while converting (in destination column). You'll find the row with problematic value.

Another method for to find the row (if there is only one problematic column) is to specify the number of beginning rows which must be skipped during import. You have ~4000 rows - skip 2000, if fail, skip then 3000 (the middle between 3000 and 4000), if not skip 1000 (the middle between 0 and 2000)... and decrease the range twice on each next import attempt until the problematic row become visible.

Of course, this allows to find only one problematic value - but there can be more than one problem...

Importing all columns as text ones and then convert all non-text to proper datatype allows you to find all errors by one operation and is preferred. But don't be surprised that some errorneous (while during import) values may be converted without error, giving correct or incorrect result (for example, date value may swap day and month).

Comment: This did help me identify my problem (I actually had to change the datatype of all but one to DO NOT IMPORT, because it would still error with text.) Then I narrowed it down to the error columns. Turns out the fields that were erroring contained newlines in them which excel did not like, and I parsed out via REGEX. Thanks for the help!